# Overwrite a value in a specific column with a variable in python text

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making this program so that the user types in something, which is stored as a variable, and then overwriting a value in a specific column in a text file with the variable. I always get the problem 
    TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
Here is my code that i need help with.

```
with open("Base.txt", "r") as f:#opening it as variable f makes it easier to call to later
        searchlines = f.readlines()#shortens the function f.readlines() to searchlines. This is easier to reference later
        infile = open("Base.txt","r+")#opens the file in reading mode
        liness = infile.readlines()#makes the variable liness to be the same as reading lines in the file
        liness =    ', '.join(liness)#adds commas onto liness, which is equal to new liness
        liness = liness.split(" ")#breaks apart the quotations
        for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
            if barcode in line:
                words = line.split(" ")#sets the word variable to split the line into quotes
                howmany =int(input("How many are your buying? "))
                quantity=int(words[3])
                if howmany < quantity:
                    with open("Base1.txt","w") as p:
                        quantity=int(words[3])
                        update=int(quantity-howmany)
                        p.write(quantity[update])
                        break
```

my whole code is

```
    import sys
import string
x = 0
menu = 0
recipt = open("Recipt.txt","r+")
recipt.seek(0)
recipt.truncate()
recipt.close()
total = 0#Makes the variable total 0, this makes it easier to work with later
while x == 0:
    menu = input("What do you want to do?\n 1)Add to the Recipt \n 2)View the Recipt \n 3)Checkout \n")#Gives the user a choice
    if menu ==  "1":
        recipt = open("Recipt.txt","a")#opens an empty text file. This will be the receipt
        y = 0
        while y == 0:
            barcode = input("What is the barcode of the item? ")
            if len(barcode) == 8:
                searchfile = open("Base.txt", "r+")#Opens the premade database file
                y = y + 1
            else:
                print("That barcode is not 8 in length.")
        with open("Base.txt", "r") as f:#opening it as variable f makes it easier to call to later
            searchlines = f.readlines()#shortens the function f.readlines() to searchlines. This is easier to reference later
            infile = open("Base.txt","r+")#opens the file in reading mode
            liness = infile.readlines()#makes the variable liness to be the same as reading lines in the file
            liness =    ', '.join(liness)#adds commas onto liness, which is equal to new liness
            liness = liness.split(" ")#breaks apart the quotations
            for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
                if barcode in line:
                    words = line.split(" ")#sets the word variable to split the line into quotes
                    howmany =int(input("How many are your buying? "))
                    quantity=int(words[3])
                    if howmany < quantity:
                        with open("Base1.txt","w") as p:
                            update=str(quantity-howmany)
                            p.write(str(quantity))
                            break
                        break
                    elif howmany==quantity:
                        update=0
                        p.write(str(update))
                        break
                    elif howmany>quantity:
                        print("We do not have that many!")
                        continue
                    line = line.replace('\n', '')#replaces line with a new line and a space
                    recipt.write(line + ' ' + howmany)#writes into the new file with the variable line and how many with a space in between
                    howmany = float(howmany)#turns the howmany variable into a float,decimal
                    prices = words[2]#prices is equal
                    prices = float(prices) 
                    totalprice = prices * howmany
                    totalprice = ("{0:.2f}").format(round(totalprice,2))
                    recipt.write(" £" + totalprice + "\n")
                    total = float(total) + float(totalprice)

                    recipt.close()
                elif barcode not in liness:
                    print("Item not found.")      
    if menu ==  "2":
        with open("Recipt.txt","r+") as f:
            for line in f:
                print(line)
        recipt.close()
    if menu ==  "3":
        recipt = open("Recipt.txt","a")
        recipt.write("£"+str(total))
        recipt.close()
        sys.exit()
```

The error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\David\Desktop\Task 2 2 Version 2.py", line 37, in <module>
    p.write(quantity(update))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

if needed. I am trying not to use csv, so please don't respond with that as an answer. I am using python 3.5.
Thanks.

Comment: What's the exact traceback you receive - that'll tell you the line the exception is occurring and give you an idea on what to fix...

Comment: *"I am trying not to use csv"* ...why? And please give a [mcve].

Comment: you forgot to close `infile` and `searchfile`

Comment: Jon Clements, i don't know what you mean, and jonrsharpe, it's a school assignment, where we are not supposed to use csv. As for the examples, minimal and complete are there, i will edit in the verifiable example now.

Comment: you call close on recipt an extra time inside menu == "2"

Comment: To all above, i have edited in the error message that highlights the line that goes wrong

Comment: pyinthesky-i did close it

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors you need to address, i've commented both of them. In both cases they revolve around your variable `quantity`. quantity is an integer, meaning you cannot do `quantity[value], quantity(value), quantity.function`

```
quantity=int(words[3])
if howmany < quantity:
    with open("Base1.txt","w") as p:
        quantity=int(words[3])
        update=int(quantity-howmany)
        p.write(quantity[update])     #### quantity is an int, so this is the reason for your initial exception, you cannot index into quantity
        break
    break
elif howmany==quantity:
    update=0
    quantity.write(update)       ### this is another exception causing bug
    break
```

you cannot call .write() on the variable quantity, as it is an integer

You commented about not knowing what a traceback was, here is an example:

```
>>> a = 5
>>> a.write(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Comment: for the first one, just `p.write(str(quantity))` - if you're just trying to write the numerical value as a string, to the file. For the second one, `quantity` should be replaced with the file handle for the file you wish to write to -- possibly `p`? and you should surround update as `str(update)` since you want to write out to the file as text.

Comment: I will try this out tomorrow, will give update. Thanks though.

Comment: It didn't do what i intended it to do. Instead it prints out the original quantity in the separate file, and not the new quantity

Comment: can you update your question w/ you current updated code